# Rails 3 + Paperclip: N+1 Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, optimization, paperclip

So, I am using the Bullet gem to try and catch N+1 queries in my Rails 3 app. However, I hit one query that I can't seem to get around.

Here's the bullet message:

```
N+1 Query detected
  User => [:profile]
  Add to your finder: :include => [:profile]
N+1 Query method call stack
  .../app/models/user.rb:38:in `full_name'
  .../config/initializers/paperclip.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
  .../app/views/photos/_photo_tiles.html.haml:4:in `_app_views_photos__photo_tiles_html_haml__787318603078146010_2192645460_1634077202131545355'
  .../app/views/photos/index.html.haml:30:in `_app_views_photos_index_html_haml___2562222078013468078_2155167020__3275303796392914006'
```

It doesn't really make sense why it would do this, though, because every user always has profile data that needs to be pulled with them, so my User model has this in it:

```
# SCOPES
default_scope includes(:profile)

# DELEGATES
delegate :first_name, :last_name, :full_name,
         :to => :profile
```

So, I'm always pulling the profile along with the user. The problem seems to stem from the inclusion of the user's full name in the file name for their uploads, found in my paperclip initializer:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :username do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.user.full_name.dehumanize
end
```

So, that call to user.full_name is being passed through to user.profile -- but profile is included!

So, anyone have any ideas how to eliminate this N+1 query?

Thanks!

Comment: How was the user and how was the attachement found in the first place? I think thats the query you need to be looking at, attachment.instance.user is already instantiated. Was it found using a finder or something else that might not use the default scope?

Comment: Hmm, well I guess that's a paperclip thing. There's no other code setting up that query in the initializer, it's a standalone method. Any insight into how Paperclip works to possibly inform a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is a true instance of N+1 query rather than a mistake by Bullet? Maybe it gets confused by the whole default_scope + delegate thing.

Have you tried running the method in question in `script/console development` while in another shell doing `tail -f log/development.log`?

This way you can see which queries are getting executed and make sure that Bullet isn't just confused.

Comment: That's interesting, I'll check it out. It hadn't occurred to me that Bullet might be at fault.